Why is Express Handlebars expecting a layouts folder instead of layout folder?
"I’m using express-handlebars for templating in my Express.js app. I have set up the layout folder, not layouts, and specified its location correctly in the configuration. However, despite my configuration, Express is expecting the folder to be named layouts (plural) and fails to find the layout file when it is named layout (singular).
I have configured the engine as follows:
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('hbs', exphbs.engine({
  extname: 'hbs',
  defaultLayout: 'layout',
  layoutDir: __dirname + '/views/layout/',  // Location of layout files
  partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/'  // Location of partials
}));

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

Despite this, I receive the following error when trying to render a page:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\path\to\your\project\views\layouts\layout.hbs'

I have a folder named layout, but Express seems to be looking for layouts instead. When I rename my folder to layouts, the app works as expected, but I want to understand why this behavior occurs and why the configuration doesn't work with the folder named layout."
"I configured express-handlebars with the layout folder. My expectation was that Express would correctly find the layout file located in views/layout/ when rendering pages. I tried the following:

I created a folder named layout inside views/.
I specified the configuration in app.js to use this folder for layouts and partials.
I expected the app to render pages using the layout.hbs from the layout folder.
However, Express is looking for a layouts folder instead and is throwing an error stating it cannot find the file. The issue only resolves when I rename the folder to layouts, but this is not ideal because I want to use layout (singular)."


I think the configuration needs to be layoutsDir, not layoutDir. See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

@76484 Thank you for your response! It worked perfectly. I do have one question, though: Even though the error was in layoutsDir, why did changing the folder name to layouts make it work? Could you explain this behaviour?

It worked because layouts is the default directory name. By having the wrong key in your config object, you left the library to use its default, layouts.

@76484  Got it! Thanks a lot for explaining. That really helped me understand the layouts folder better!

You're welcome.
